# XPages and REST : Error 500 from IBM Notes Client

Tags: java, json, rest, xpages, lotus-notes

i'm trying to get a JSON representation of a view with an ajax request from a XPage.
First of all, i did it with the following url `https://myserver/mydb/myview?readviewentries&outputformat=JSON&count=-1`.

It works in browsers but not in IBM Notes Client (my application have to work in the both), i got an error 404, i read on internet that we can't use that syntax in the Notes client. So i tried to use the restService element from XPages to get my JSON.

I create a XPage with the following code :

```
<xe:restService id="restService1" pathInfo="JoursFeries">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewJsonService defaultColumns="true"
            databaseName="Applis/JoursFeries.nsf" viewName="JoursFeries">
        </xe:viewJsonService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

I changed my URL to call my Rest service like that : `myXpage.xsp/JoursFeries` (My new XPage is on the same database as the calling XPage). One more time, it works on browsers but still not in IBM Notes client. I called it like that :

```
var feries = {
    url : "xRestJoursFeries.xsp/JoursFeries",
    handleAs : "json",
    sync : true,
    preventCache : this.urlPreventCache,
    load : function(json) {
        // My callback function
    }
}

dojo.xhrGet(feries);
```

When I activate my XPage debugger in Notes client, I just can see that the page returns an error 500, my console just said that :

WARNING CLFAD####W: State data not available for /xRestJoursFeries because no control tree was found in the cache. ::class.methot=com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl_restoreView() ::thread=Thread-348 ::loggername=anonymous

I tried many parameters on my XPages which provides the REST service, but without success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of the Notes client are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 9 on both, client and server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL's in xPINC are different. You will need to change the URL's. Check this page for some info.
http://xomino.com/2013/02/03/xpinc-browser-url-format-and-why-my-demo-failed-at-ibmconnect-part-2/

You could utilize @ClientType() in an if statement to choose onee URL over another.

You could also run xpages on the server and the app would work in both.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't think this solution solved my problem. I don't get an error 404 with my AJAX request, so I suppose that my URL is correct.
I get an error 500 with the error message that I pasted yesterday in my first post.

Comment: To be more specific about what I want to do, I just want to do this : http://xcellerant.net/2014/04/22/dojo-in-xpages-19-using-ajax-to-retrieve-data-from-a-rest-service/ and use it from xPINC

Comment: Would it be possible to run the xPage on the server? It should work since you are running the app on D9

Comment: Ok It works when I run my xPages on the server. In my case it's not a problem to do this, thank you for your help ! 
If I understand, when I do this, xPINC act just like another web browser ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have this same problem with a couple of my apps, xpinc was not a requirement so I have not gone into the problem that in depth. If there was a way to use a javascript console in xpinc I might be able to find a solution.